# Aggregating a variable per time value

Tags: stata

I want to generate the `Price2` variable which is a sum of `price` value by each second and add this new value to the last row of each time values which are the same.

Here is a sample of my data (except for `Price2` variable). The result is the `price2` var. which is shown below. `Day` and `Time` variables are strings.

```
    +------+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+
    | Name |    Day    |   Time   | Price |   Price2    |
    +------+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+
    | A    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     1 |            .|
    | A    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     4 |            .|
    | A    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     3 |            8|
    | A    | 24-Mar-08 | 11:03:12 |     1 |            .|
    | A    | 24-Mar-08 | 11:03:12 |     4 |            5|
    | A    | 25-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     3 |            .|
    | A    | 25-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     8 |           11|
    | A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:13:59 |     3 |            .|
    | A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:13:59 |     2 |            .|
    | A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:13:59 |     5 |            .|
    | A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:13:59 |     3 |           13|
    | A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:59:01 |     1 |            1|
    | B    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     3 |            .|
    | B    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     4 |            7|
    | B    | 24-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     3 |            .|
    | B    | 24-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     5 |            8|
    | B    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     7 |            .|
    | B    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     4 |            .|
    | B    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     2 |           13|
    | B    | 25-Mar-08 | 12:00:00 |     6 |            6|
    +------+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+
```

How can I calculate `Price2` variable using Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that data as code, as below, and as in my answer to your previous thread, is much easier for people to work with. This is similar in spirit to your example above.

```
clear
input str1 Name str9(Day Time) float(Price Size)
"A" "24-Mar-08" "10:30:01" 1 3
"A" "24-Mar-08" "10:30:01" 4 4
"A" "24-Mar-08" "10:30:01" 3 2
"A" "24-Mar-08" "11:03:12" 1 4
"A" "24-Mar-08" "11:03:12" 4 1
"A" "25-Mar-08" "10:30:01" 3 4
"A" "25-Mar-08" "10:30:01" 8 2
"A" "25-Mar-08" "11:13:59" 3 2
"A" "25-Mar-08" "11:13:59" 2 4
"A" "25-Mar-08" "11:13:59" 5 5
"A" "25-Mar-08" "11:13:59" 3 3
"A" "25-Mar-08" "11:59:01" 1 5
"B" "24-Mar-08" "10:30:01" 3 6
"B" "24-Mar-08" "10:30:01" 4 1
"B" "24-Mar-08" "11:30:01" 3 2
"B" "24-Mar-08" "11:30:01" 5 1
"B" "25-Mar-08" "11:30:01" 7 3
"B" "25-Mar-08" "11:30:01" 4 6
"B" "25-Mar-08" "11:30:01" 2 2
"B" "25-Mar-08" "12:00:00" 6 2
end

bysort Name Day Time: egen wanted = total(Price)
by Name Day Time: replace wanted = . if _n < _N 

list, sepby(Name Day Time) 

     +-----------------------------------------------------+
     | Name         Day       Time   Price   Size   wanted |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    A   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       1      3        . |
  2. |    A   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       4      4        . |
  3. |    A   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       3      2        8 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  4. |    A   24-Mar-08   11:03:12       1      4        . |
  5. |    A   24-Mar-08   11:03:12       4      1        5 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  6. |    A   25-Mar-08   10:30:01       3      4        . |
  7. |    A   25-Mar-08   10:30:01       8      2       11 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  8. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:13:59       3      2        . |
  9. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:13:59       2      4        . |
 10. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:13:59       5      5        . |
 11. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:13:59       3      3       13 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
 12. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:59:01       1      5        1 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
 13. |    B   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       3      6        . |
 14. |    B   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       4      1        7 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
 15. |    B   24-Mar-08   11:30:01       3      2        . |
 16. |    B   24-Mar-08   11:30:01       5      1        8 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
 17. |    B   25-Mar-08   11:30:01       7      3        . |
 18. |    B   25-Mar-08   11:30:01       4      6        . |
 19. |    B   25-Mar-08   11:30:01       2      2       13 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
 20. |    B   25-Mar-08   12:00:00       6      2        6 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------+
```